# is it possible to show one div and hide all other div on toggle..?

Tags: jquery

I have three headings and all three have some description.
when i click on first heading, i can see its description.
when i click on 2nd heading, i can see its description.
my code is here:
js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".content").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
jQuery(".heading").click(function()
{
jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
});
});
</script>
```

css:

```
.layer1 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 500px;
}

.heading {
margin: 1px;
color: #fff;
padding: 3px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
background-color:#c30;
}
.content {
padding: 5px 10px;
background-color:#fafafa;
}
p { padding: 5px 0; }
```

html code:

```
<div class="layer1">
    <p class="heading">Header-1 </p>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    <p class="heading">Header-2</p>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    <p class="heading">Header-3</p>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
</div>
```

Now i want that when i click one 1 heading, other description have to hide and just description of 1st heading is visible.
how to do this..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hide all `.content` siblings of the chosen `.content`:

```
jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
    jQuery(this)
          .next(".content").slideToggle(500)
          .siblings(".content").slideUp(500);
});
```

Comment: I can not get the output when i put this code in my js. where to write this code..?

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
        jQuery(".content").slideUp();
        jQuery(this).next(".content").slideDown(500);
      });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cUyhe/

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
        jQuery(".content").not(jQuery(this).next(".content")).slideUp(500);
        jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UxcwU/)

Comment: funny how two guys sent the same answer with the same comment!

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
   //toggle the componenet with class msg_body 
   jQuery(".heading").click(function() 
   {
      jQuery(this).parent().find(".opened").slideToggle(500, function(){
         $(this).removeClass('opened');
      });
      jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500, function(){
         $(this).addClass('opened');
      }); 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: maybe because your `.content` doesn't have `display:none;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in click event..

```
jQuery(".heading").click(function()
    {
        jQuery(".content").hide();
        jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
    });
```

Hope that works for you..

Answer (score 0):

You got to identify it to do so. You can use classes to identify by creating a clone with another name, than you can get the tags by class and hide without hidding everything.