# is it possible to show one div and hide all other div on toggle(three toggle)..?

Tags: jquery

hey guys thanx for your last help in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882708/is-it-possible-to-show-one-div-and-hide-all-other-div-on-toggle).
now i want to know that in place of one toggle button how can i use three toggle button?
my html code is:

```
<div class="layer1">
<span class="heading">Header-1 </span><span class="heading">Header-1 </span><span class="heading">Header-1 </span>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
<span class="heading">Header-2</span><span class="heading">Header-1 </span><span class="heading">Header-1 </span>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
<span class="heading">Header-3</span><span class="heading">Header-1 </span><span class="heading">Header-1 </span>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
```

and css is :

```
.layer1 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 300px;
}

.heading {
 margin: 1px;
 color: #fff;
padding: 3px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
background-color:#c30;
}
.content {
padding: 5px 10px;
background-color:#fafafa;
}
p { padding: 5px 0; }
```

and jquery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
        jQuery(this)
            .next(".content").slideToggle(500)
            .siblings(".content").slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

i want that i can open sub item of header-1 by clicking on any of three header button
but its not working. only 3rd button is working.
i think there will be some change in my jquery.
help me i am not clear.

Comment: Could you provide more clear explanation... header-1 doesn't have any sub items.. only siblings

Comment: I got the answer. they are copy past and  want that. and i want same effect with all of that three spans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.next('.content')` only looks at the next element, and if it matches '.content' then it uses it, otherwise it ignores it. `.nextAll` gets all the next elements ahead of it and putting :first after the class name means it will only select the first one it finds.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
        jQuery(this)
            .nextAll(".content:first").slideToggle(500)
            .siblings(".content").slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KP55t/

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".content").hide();
            jQuery(".heading").click(function() {

                jQuery(this)
                    .nextAll(".content").eq(0).slideToggle(500)
                    .siblings(".content").slideUp(500);
            });
        });
```